# How to find all combinations for slightly big positive number pairs in R

Tags: r, combinations

I'm developing a method in R, where I am in need of all combinations of the elements of X (of size n) taken m < n at a time.

For example, if `X = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and `m = 3`, it produces `{1 2 3}, {1 2 4}, {1 2 5}, {1 3 4}, {1 3 5}, {1 4 5}, {2 3 4}, {2 3 5}, {2 4 5},` and `{3 4 5}`.

I am aware of the fact that the function '`combn(5,3)`' does this task. But I need to get the combination of slightly bigger positive integer, say '`combn(4000, 20)`'. This base function could not produce for '`combn(100,10)`'. It says

> "Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) :    invalid 'ncol'
>   value (too large or NA)

In addition: Warning message:

> In combn(100, 10) : NAs introduced by coercion"

How can I get all combinations for slightly bigger positive integers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `choose(4000,20)` to see just how astronomically huge that number of combinations would be. There are fewer stars in the universe, or gains of sand on the earth.

Comment: Thanks @A.Webb for your comment. I think I need to reduce my search space by using some pruning techniques, say something like `combn(1000, 5)`.

Comment: Perhaps [this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301986/how-can-i-parallelize-combn) migh be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz for the link. This is a great implementation. I can now generate the combinations in parts: get a part, work on it, and then generate next part and work, and so on. Hence it will not take large space at a time.